# Is symmetrical current perfectly symmetrical beyond analysis?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, theory

Lets suppose that a circuit was constructed with almost identical components and wires to a ridiculous accuracy. When we say that a current is equal due to symmetry after a branch in a node with circuit analysis, would a real circuit built with the specifications above actually contain an equal distribution of the current between both paths? It seems logical that they would vary slightly, how slight is that and how dependent on the components that you used is the difference in current? What is the magnitude of the variation (milli-amps, nano-amps, single electrons)?

Comment: all circuits have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise which will not be the same for 2 identical circuits

Answer (score 2):

In general you'd have to do a [sensitivity analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis), and different circuits might well have different sensitivities. One way is to start with a theoretically perfect circuit and perturb each of the component values slightly and look at the resulting change in whatever parameter you are considering. That can be done with SPICE, for example.

While some simple circuits might have relatively low sensitivity- you change the resistor value by 0.1% and the current mismatch in two branches changes by about 0.1%- it's possible for the sensitivity to be much, much worse, even in linear circuits, for example, if two almost-equal voltages are just about canceling, a small change in one of the voltages can result in a large increase in current.

Comment: Are there any applications where this might be more or less important?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Any relevant examples?

Answer (score 0):

Error = Perfection - "Ridiculous Accuracy"

Lacking specs on ridiculous accuracy, error is undefined.

Comment: Well, this is more of a theoretical question so if you have some suggestions, then I can edit the question :)

Comment: In theory, the currents are precisely equal. In practice, they are either equal enough for all practical purposes, or not. So, as a theoretical question, the answer is that they are equal. If you'd like an answer in practice, build and measure.

Comment: Remember that adding a real current meter into one branch (or even  adding "matched" current meters to two branches) of a well matched circuit might be enough that the matching is no longer "ridiculously" good.